# Prove or disprove $32$ has $8$ primitive roots; they are all odd numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that the order must divide $\varphi(32)=16$

I was able to make a list of all the elements relatively prime to $32$ and noticed none of them have order $16$ is there a better way to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Powers of $2$ larger than $4$ do not have primitive roots.

The best we can say is that there are elements of order $2^{k-2} \bmod 2^k$. There are $2^{k-3}$ of them.

Indeed, $U(2^k) \cong C_2 \times C_{2^{k-2}}$ for $k \ge 3$.